# Leverage browser caching - expiry dates are not being set

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache

I'm using https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ and it shows that every image on my site is not being cached. I've tried using W3 Total Cache, editing .htaccess with this:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

And this:

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|svg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=84600, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Code, but to no avail. 
Why are the images not being cached? Is there a way to fix this?

The link to PageSpeed: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=darbas.pcz.lt

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the output at least of the scan or give us the website or something?

Comment: Yes. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=darbas.pcz.lt

Comment: You probably dont even have the mod_expires module loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in the word `plus` to make it work,

otherwise your saying it `expires when its accessed one month`.  which makes no sense.

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-httpd-php "access plus 30 seconds"
```

Comment: [link](https://codeshare.io/anKlnG) This is how my .htaccess file looks like at the moment, but it's still not working. Am i still doing something wrong or perhaps some plugin might be interfering, such as Autoptimize? I'm using Wordpress CMS by the way.

Comment: Never mind. I think you might be right about mod_expires not being loaded. I just don't know if i can check that somehow. Thank you a lot anyways :)

Comment: Just get rid of the  `<IfModule mod_expires.c>`  part  and the  `</IfModule>`  part surrounding your expires calls,  then reload the page -- if your website doesn't load then mod_expires isn't loaded ;)

Comment: Also make sure that you have  AllowOverrides set for your virtual host in the httpd.conf